# Simple gradle script error

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Here is my gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

when I run it I have:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'G:\grad\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'grad'.

  > Could not find method ?apply() for arguments [{plugin=java}] on root project 'grad'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have some invisible character before `apply`. Delete the file, and start from scratch. Re-typing those 3 words should be easy enough.